# "It will become the talk of Paris" - translation into French

Tags: traduction, anglais

"This innovative Canadian TV comedy will soon become **the talk of Paris** once again."

I'd like to know, when a certain TV star or program, or a scandalous politician or company is expected to become the center of attention, in a positive way or negative way, in a certain country or city and most people there will talk and gossip about them, how can this be said in French?

Answer (score 2):

> [Défrayer la chronique. 
>  Faire la/les manchette(s).](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=talk%20of%20the%20town&index=enw&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)
>  Être
>   ce dont tout le monde parle. [on pourrait remplacer *ce* par
>   *l'émission*]
>  Être le sujet de toutes les conversations.
>  Être le sujet de l'heure. (Québec ?) [on pourrait remplacer *le sujet*
>   par *l'émission*]
>   [Faire fureur.](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_fureur)

Answer (score 2):

Given that the word "*again*" is included in your example, I'd express the idea as:

> Cette comédie télé avant-gardiste canadienne ne devrait plus tarder à **refaire parler d'elle** à Paris.

... as opposed to: "***faire parler d'elle***".

"*Défrayer la chronique*" tends to carry a negative connotation, so I'd swap the subject with something more fitting:

> Tous les scandales de falsification de données entourant Carlos Ghosn ne vont pas tarder à **défrayer** à nouveau **la chronique** à Paris.

Another (simpler) option is:

> Ces derniers temps, les Parisiens **ne parlent** (**plus**) **que de** ça.

Interestingly, "*[faire le buzz](http://www.pepperconseil.com/20-english-words-that-should-be-banished-from-french/)*" is cited as one of the "*20 English words that should be banished from French*":

- "*Faire le buzz*" (to make a buzz) in proper French would be "*defrayer la chronique*" (to be the subject of gossip) or "*créer l’événement*" (to create an event).

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> [Faire le buzz](http://www.expression-francaise.fr/faire-le-buzz/) !

Answer (score 1):

*être la coqueluche de Paris* does the trick but applies only to people.  The TLF gives the following example from Léon Daudet about Oscar Wilde :

*Il était la coqueluche des milieux londoniens.*

Now was Wilde the talk of London for positive or negative reasons?  Probably both!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a couple of new suggestions:

> Ça va faire **causer dans les chaumières** !
>
> Ça va faire [**du bruit dans Landerneau**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cela_va_faire_du_bruit_dans_Landerneau) ! (but here the impact will be limited in space)

Answer (score -1):

je dirais "devenir le sujet de conversation" ... cette série canadienne va bientôt devenir le sujet de conversation en France...
this will be the traduce in french but the chances it'll become really the talk are poor... (je suis francais et il y a tellement de séries en lice que les chances de devenir un classique sont plutôt minces)