# "Faire le buzz" / "faire du buzz"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, anglicismes

Les expressions « faire le buzz / faire du buzz » sont-elles assez répandues en dehors des mondes technologique internet, entreprise, marketing, etc. ?

Comment doit-on prononcer *buzz* afin d'être bien compris, à l'anglaise ou à la française ?

Les expressions « bouche à oreilles », « téléphone arabe » et « faire du bourdonnement » sont-elles équivalentes à « faire le buzz » ?

Comment: Etre cité dans les talk show et la presse trash, c'est complétement "faire le buzz". Mais ça n'est aucunement du bouche à oreille ou du téléphone arabe. Le buzz peut tout à fait être organisé et institutionnel. Je dirait même que Macron ou Trump sont des spécialistes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Quasiment) personne ne prononce *buzz* à la française ([**byz**]), comme **buse**.

La prononciation anglaise la plus courante est [**bʌz**] et la prononciation française habituelle s'en approche : [**bœ:z**], où la voyelle se prononce comme dans *b**eu**rre*, *j**eu**ne*, ***œu***f ou *fl**i**rt*). En voici [un exemple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrfRAr7LpxY) dans une vidéo. La voyelle anglaise est plus proche du **A** que la française. *Buzz* en anglais est presque prononcé comme ***base*** en français.

L'expression initiale était ***[faire du buzz](https://semiologie-television.com/2007/06/faire-du-buzz-ou-la-naissance-dune-expression/)*** (à l'image de *faire du bruit*) mais elle a assez vite évolué en ***faire le buzz***. Elle est née d'Internet et signifie qu'une information se transmet rapidement sans suivre les canaux de diffusion/promotion habituels (publicité, journaux). Il s'agit d'une transmission de personne à personne, via les différents réseaux sociaux, la messagerie classique (emails, sms) ou oralement.

L'expression ***de bouche à oreille*** correspond bien à l'idée de la transmission individuelle. Elle était déjà utilisée dans le même sens avant que *buzz* apparaisse. Elle a cependant aussi un côté confidence, rumeurs chuchotées à l'oreille, qui me semble moins présent dans *buzz*.

L'expression ***téléphone arabe*** est née lors de l'époque coloniale pour rendre compte de la rapidité et l'efficacité de la communication orale pour répandre des informations à une population dépourvue de moyens technologiques (téléphone). Elle a donné naissance à un jeu où chaque participant chuchote à l'oreille de son voisin une phrase originale, et où la dégradation et l'évolution, accidentelles ou provoquées, de la phrase font rire tout le monde à la fin. On ne peut pas remplacer *ça fait le buzz* par *ça fait le téléphone arabe* mais on peut éventuellement dire que le téléphone arabe est un support de transmission du *buzz*.

L'expression ***faire du bourdonnement*** n'est pas très idiomatique. Il s'agit simplement de la traduction littérale de *buzz* : bourdonnement d'un insecte en anglais, clairement une onomatopée que l'on retrouve d'ailleurs dans le français *bzz* ou *bzzz*. On pourrait dire ***faire du bruit*** mais ce n'est pas tout à fait la même chose. Ce qui *fait du bruit*, c'est souvent une information secrète divulguée qui suscite des réactions émotionnelles fortes.

Comment: La prononciation anglaise, c'est avec [ʌ], pas [ə]. [ə], [œ] et [ø] sont des approximations plausibles en français. Je ne vois pas le rapport avec *jeûne* et *pleureuse* : pourquoi utiliserait-on le même son dans ces trois mots ? Et je ne comprends pas comment tu prononces *pleureuse* : [-ʁøz], [-ʁœz], [-ʁœ.zə], [-ʁø,zø], … ?

Comment: @Gilles Tu as raison. C'est bien plus souvent [ʌ] qui est rapporté. Je me suis fait avoir par le premier dictionnaire (et le seul, mon erreur) que j'ai consulté qui indique [**bəz**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buzz). Le rapport avec *pleureuse*, c'est qu'avec l'accent méridional son *-euse* final se prononce comme se prononce, si mes oreilles ne me jouent pas de tours, *buzz* en français. Les gens "sans accent" comme on dit ne font pas rimer *buzz* et *gueuse* par exemple, mais je peux me tromper. Je prononce donc *pleureuse* [pløʁœz] et *buzz* [bœz].

Answer (score 2):

Comme tu l'as justement dit, *faire le buzz* est principalement utilisé dans le domaine de la communication, des réseaux sociaux, du marketing et d'internet.
Ne connaissant pas l'alphabet phonétique, si tu veux prononcer buzz en France celui-ci sera prononcé *b e ze* (not bèze), with a neutral *e* as in *celui* for example (à l'anglaise donc).

Les expressions que tu as cité ont un sens différent:

- Bouche à oreilles = transmettre une information a des connaissances via différents moyens (à l'oral lors d'une discussion, via des échanges téléphoniques, textuels etc)
- Téléphone arabe: transmettre une information ayant un sens différent à la fin de la chaîne par rapport au sens original. Une dégradation de la qualité de l'information en somme. "Un homme a assassiné 2 personnes à l'aide d'un revolver" => (personne suivante) 
  "Un homme a tué 3 personnes à l'aide d'un bazooka".

*Faire du bourdonnement* serait l'expression que je trouve la plus proche de *faire du buzz* ou encore *faire du bruit* et même *faire parler de*.

Comment: Dans le langage courant la très très grande majorité des gens utilisant l'expression *téléphone arabe* l'utilisent avec le sens que j'ai donné, autant lui donner le sens le plus courant, c'est comme les professeurs de langues qui t'apprennent du langage oublié, ça n'apporte au final pas grand chose à l'apprentissage de la langue... J'ai volontairement pas écrit *beuze* puisque le son *eu* que l'on retrouve dans *pleureuse* par exemple n'est pas celui que nous utilisons en france mais bien un *e* neutre. On ne dit pas j'ai fais le *beuze* , mais bien j'ai fais le *be - ze*.

Comment: J'ai du mal à comprendre ton *be - ze* ([bøzø] ?), le mot n'ayant qu'une syllabe en français comme en anglais.

Comment: @jlliagre Tout simplement qu'en langue française le son "e" est différent du son "eu", et buzz se prononce bien avec le son "e" et non avec le son "eu". Essaye de prononcer "buzz" puis "beuze", tu verras que la prononciation est différente. Le doublement du Z explique la prononciation similaire à *beurre* comme tu l'as a juste titre utilisé comme exemple dans ton commentaire.

Comment: La prononciation du français n'est pas uniforme, et *e* comme *eu* peuvent avoir chacun différentes prononciations. Pour ma part, comme quelques millions de français, je prononce *buzz* comme "*beuze*" ou *pleureuse*, d'où l'intérêt d'utiliser l'alphabet phonétique international pour se faire comprendre. De toute façon, mon commentaire ne concernait pas la prononciation de la voyelle en question, mais le fait que ta représentation peut laisser croire que *buzz* est réalisé avec deux syllabes et deux voyelles identiques, ce qui n'est jamais le cas en français, même dans le sud de la France.

Answer (score 1):

Uniquement sur le sujet des équivalents. Le terme [buzz](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/buzz/10910386?q=buzz#917172) a « envahi le champ de l'information » ; « *Bourdonnement* est officiellement admis en [aéronautique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26537738) » ; « *Bouche à oreille* le remplace dans le domaine de l’économie et de la gestion » nous dit l'[Académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/dire-ne-pas-dire/recherche?titre=buzz) qui ajoute :

> Dans la langue courante, *Faire le buzz sur l’internet, dans les
>   réseaux sociaux* pourrait être remplacé par *Faire parler, Faire du
>   bruit, Créer une rumeur, Faire la rumeur*, expressions qui traduisent,
>   comme l’onomatopée *Buzz*, la vaine agitation créée autour d’un
>   phénomène passager. (Académie française)

---

On a déjà [proposé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_(marketing)#Proposition_de_francisation) de le franciser par [*ramdam*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ramdam) (tapage, vacarme) et des équivalents de [*to be the talk of the town*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/37145) fonctionneraient aussi pour la locution. Quand il s'agit d'un type de publicité dans le domaine du marketing, le nom *publicité* avec la précision *sur les réseaux/médias sociaux, sur Internet*, suffit largement et le terme [*rumeur*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8374417) est utile autrement. La difficulté avec la locution c'est qu'elle contient le verbe *faire* alors que le *téléphone arabe* et le *bouche à oreille* sont des moyens de créer l'effervescence tandis que le *bourdonnement* n'est pas exactement idiomatique ou trop relié au bruit au sens propre comme on l'a expliqué ailleurs. On préférerait dire *faire des vagues* sur Internet pour connoter la vague de la propagation (pour rester dans le lexique de la *navigation*) plutôt que la référence sonore rappelant l'insecte et son butinage etc.

En résumé **faire parler/du bruit/la rumeur** sur l'internet/dans les réseaux sociaux sont des équivalents mieux articulés avec le semi-auxiliaire. On trouve la métaphore avec le bourdonnement peu apte à décrire ce dont il s'agit, quoique tout nous semble meilleur que le choix du mot *buzz*, inutile, imprécis, intraduisible de prime abord parce qu'on ne s'est pas donné la peine de réfléchir à comment en inscrire le sens dans l'univers linguistique du français.